# Transient current consumption of an opamp

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, transient

How to select a voltage converter for a chip based on its input current? I know, that I should look for I<sub>sup</sub> in the datasheet. But what about pulse current?

For example I have OPA4180 (four-channel op amp) with dual supply. The datasheet says, its quiescent current is 0.525 mA(max).
I was told to use three LM2664 (I<sub>out</sub> = 50 mA) in parallel. In total I<sub>out</sub> = 150 mA.

But I couldn't get any explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

Quiescent current is amplifier supply current with no output current.

Output current has to be sourced/sunk from/to the appropriate supply rail.

Output current is limited to a few 10s of mA in most small amplifiers, either just from the capability of the output drivers, or intentionally so that a chip-damaging current doesn't flow if you short circuit the output briefly (easy to do with a careless 'scope probe).

Different amplifiers specify that they will survive for different times, depending on what rail you short the output to.

If you were told to use three amplifiers in parallel, then presumably somebody wants a total output current in excess of what a single amplifier will produce. I did a design once where to get the current output from a 50 Ω output impedance, I used three opamps, each driving a 150 Ω resistor, the resistors then went in parallel to the output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for poorly worded question. I was told to use three voltage converters in parallel to power four-channel opamp (one is unused).